# how to call a column in a dataframe with a value

Tags: python

How can I call a column(name or index) in a python dataframe by using the values in that column

```
dataframe=pandas.DataFrame({'col1':'val1','col2':'val2'})
```

how can I call a column with input as the values(val1,val2)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do with an example

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. How your output should be?

Comment: Does your data only have 1 row/observation for each columns?

Answer (score 0):

> this might help.

```
dataframe=pandas.DataFrame({'col1':'val1','col2':'val2'}) 
dataframe.['col1']
dataframe.['col2']
dataframe.['col2']
```

with values(in a row) you can't fetch column name from that.
or else i think its not possible , still if any one knows they can do try

Comment: What should this `dataframe.['col1']` do?